# Mail is not receive while click submit button

Tags: php

am tried to send mail to multiple user...if i use two gmail mail id means i will got mail properly ..if i try to use something mail like info@xxx.com means i will not get mail it will show error message..i have to done today itself please anyone help me.

This is  my coding:

```
<?php
$name = $_POST["name"]; 
$lname = $_POST["lname"]; 
$email = $_POST["email"]; 
$location = $_POST["location"]; 
$org = $_POST["org"]; 
$inquiry = $_POST["inquiry"]; 
$message = $_POST["message"]; 
$message = "Name :" . $name . "\n" 
         . "Last Name :" . $lname . "\n" 
         . "Email :" . $email . "\n" 
         . "Location :" . $location . "\n" 
         . "Organization :" . $org . "\n" 
         . "Inquiry :" . $inquiry . "\n" 
         . "Questions/Comments  :" . $message;

$subject = "Visitor Enquiry";
$to = "dev@xxxcom";
$to = "info@XXx.com";

if(mail($to, $subject, $message)){ ?>
<script>
    alert("Thank You for Contacting Us,We'll Get Back To You Soon");
    window.location = "contact-us.php";
</script>
<?php
echo "We Received Your enquiry, We'll get back to you soon";
} else { 
echo "There were some errors sending enquiry, please try again";
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me...and sorry inconvenience this my very fist use stack overflow i really dunno how to use properly

Comment: Of course it only sends to a single email - you're replacing the variable. You need to run the entire `mail()` function twice.

Comment: but i tried two gmail mail ids  i was got mail properly ..i also try to use single mail using info@xxx@.com i will not get mail it echo error message

Answer (score 1):

```
bool mail (string $to , string $subject , string $message 
           [, string $additional_headers [, string $additional_parameters]])
```

if $to is a valid mail address then mail will definitely be received

Comment: yes it  will receive...only using gmail...if i used info@xxx.com means it will echo error message

Comment: @PoovarasanRK,  if $to = info@xxx.com and "info@xxx.com" is a valid email then it will receive email from mail() function too.

Comment: ,if i used xxx@gmail.com means i will get it,,,,but thing is i try info@xxx.com will not get mail it will show error message like"There were some errors sending enquiry, please try again"...do you think is any error in coding

Comment: do you want to send same mail to multiple users?

Comment: yes one is like xxx@gmail.com...and another one is info@xxx.com.....the problem is getting while using info@xxx.com only and xxx@gmail.com it will works fine

Comment: Ok in this case try this way $to="abc@xyz.com, xyz@abc.com" ;

Comment: i tried this way also ...but did not works using only info@xxx.com

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75581/discussion-between-manish-shukla-and-poovarasan-rk).